# How to change default python enviroment

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda

I am using a Mac and it is using Anaconda Python by default. How do I change my default Python enviroment to the standard version? And is there any difference between Anaconda Python and regular Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "regular python" is a system-wide package visible via the `$PATH` environment variable and has nothing to do with anaconda. A "conda python" is a python interpreter specific to a conda environment.

Calling python by default will trigger the system-wide package. First activating a conda environment and then calling python triggers the interpreter in that environment

Comment: Thank you! But to make my question clearer, previously I think somehow my default python is changed to conda python. Now I want change my default python to the system-wide python.

Comment: You'll have to deactivate your current conda environment